# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it firewall issue

Tags: c#-4.0

I am doing socket-client programming in C#.
I have written TCPListener on Socket server side.
It works fine when I try to connect to it from client side on same machine. But if Socket server and client both are on different machine, I get exception saying "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".
I checked socket information like ip address and port number on both the side which are absolutely correct.
I checked Antivirus log, it clearly stated that Antivirus/Firewall blocking the ip traffic.
I can't change Antivirus/Firewall settings as these are disabled by an Administrator.

Is there any programmatic way to tackle this problem? Is there any option while writing TCPLister or socket client which can provide me solution to tackle issue of Firewall.

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What antivirus solution are you using? And what is the version of the .NET framework you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this could be done. If the firewall blocks the traffic, the firewall needs to be configured accordingly so traffic is allowed. There's no other way.